# Are processes in square brackets scheduled in the same way as other processes?

Tags: kernel, process, scheduling

`ps(1)`, with the `-f` option, will output processes for which there is no associated command line in square brackets, like so:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Aug28 ?        00:07:42 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:01 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root         6     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H-kblockd]
root         8     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         9     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:02:14 [ksoftirqd/0]
root        10     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:05:33 [rcu_preempt]
root        11     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:01:36 [rcuc/0]
root        12     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [rcub/0]
root        13     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:07 [migration/0]
root        14     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/0]
root        16     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        17     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        18     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:00 [idle_inject/1]
root        19     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:05 [migration/1]
root        20     2  0 Aug28 ?        00:00:55 [rcuc/1]
```

Are these processes scheduled like other processes?

Comment: Those "processes for which they is no associated command line" are usually referred to as "kernel threads".

Comment: @JosephSible Usually, but not always. One example, userspace processes that became defunct will have square brackets around them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Linux, `ps` and `top` handle information made available by the kernel in `/proc`, for each process, in a directory named after the pid. This includes two files, `comm` and `cmdline`; `comm` is the process’s command name, and `cmdline` is the process’s command line, *i.e.* the arguments it was provided with (including its own “name”). `ps` and `top` use square brackets to distinguish between the two: if a process has a command line, then the `args` field (also known as `CMD`) outputs that; otherwise it outputs the command name, surrounded with square brackets.

This is described in [the `ps` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS), for `args`:

> Sometimes the process args will be unavailable; when this happens, `ps` will instead print the executable name in brackets.

Processes without process arguments include processes constructed without *any* command line (not even `argv[0]`), such as kernel threads, and processes which have lost their command line, *i.e.* defunct processes, also known as zombies (identifiable by the `<defunct>` suffix).

None of this changes the scheduling properties: all processes are scheduled in the same way, according to their state, priority, etc.

Comment: It also includes processes that have executed a command without argument, not even `argv[0]` (which usually doesn't happen). Try with `perl -e 'exec {"/bin/sh"} ()'` for instance.

Comment: Both comm and cmdline are modifiable in Linux. The first via a prctl(PR_SET_NAME), the second by just overwriting the argv strings in process memory.