# why ps not see sleep process?

Tags: linux, ps, sleep

I creart the first terminal ,  then I use "sleep 1000 &" and I found it by "ps".
The problem is when I creat the second terminal and put "ps" ,there is no sleep process.
I want to know why ?

[image](my homework say "hint: TTY column" )

Comment: Hint: What else is not displayed in the output.

Comment: You mean beceuse the tty column I cannt see other output like the "sleep" ?

Comment: Unclear. Did you start a second sleep in the second terminal? Or are you expecting pts/2 to tell you what is going on in pts/1? If you run ps in both terminals, you will find the PIDs for both bash and ps are different in pts/1 and pts/2.

Comment: Just one sleep.It in the first terminal. I mean I creat two terminals.

Comment: I want to konw if there are someting connections between the 【phenomenon】and the tty column

Comment: If you’re referring to the square brackets which are sometimes displayed, see [this Q&A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/548818/86440).

Comment: No,no,no.Thanks a lot,but I have founded the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `ps` only shows processes attached to the current terminal (tty): in your case, your shell and `ps` itself (both on `pts/2`). You need to lift this restriction to see `sleep`; for example

```
ps -e
```

See `man ps` for the many options available to filter processes.

Comment: I use `ps auxw` since old habits from SunOS3

Comment: yes, I found the sleep.

Comment: Thanks and one more question . So what the correlation it have with 【tty column】?

Comment: Read first line of answer.

Comment: A “tty” is a terminal: `ps` only shows processes on the same terminal, *i.e.* with the same value in the TTY column. With `ps -e` you’ll see many different values, including “?” (no terminal).

Comment: PID TTY          TIME CMD
The value mearns "TTY"? In my computer it shows "pts/2".Is it the value you say?

Comment: The column with the “TTY” header is the “TTY column”, and it lists the ttys. On your terminal that’s `pts/2`, but if you run `ps -e` you’ll see other values.

Comment: Oh I see.That's very nice of you.You really help me a lot .Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I create the second terminal and put "ps" ,there is no `sleep` process.

With some (not all) interactive shells, the `sleep`  could be a shell builtin invoking e.g. [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) (exactly as `cd`  is a shell builtin invoking [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)).

When that is the case, you won't see any `sleep` [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) because there is none. The process which is then [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html)-ing is your [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell); you could even write your own shell interpreter (look into [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell) for an easy but a little bit buggy example).

Many Linux shells are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) software (or [free software](https://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software)), so please study their source code to find out if they do call [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) or [usleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) -or even appropriately [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html), etc ...- See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [select_tut(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html). Read more about [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and think of those done by your shell (or observe them with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) or [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) or a debugger) .

Many Linux distributions have [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) as the usual interactive shell. But you could install [zsh](https://zsh.org/) or [fish](https://fishshell.com/) or [es](https://wryun.github.io/es-shell/) as your login shell (with [chsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chsh.1.html)).

My personal preference is `zsh` (whose [autocompletion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocomplete) facilities on Debian are outstanding).

Consider reading some [textbook about *Operating Systems*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and/or coding your own [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) as an exercise, or extending some existing one (e.g. by adding a `sleep` builtin, if it does not have one).

Comment: I dont konw if it doesnt exist,why I see it in the first terminal by "ps"?

Comment: Did you downloaded and studied the source code of your shell? Did you code your own Unix shell?

Comment: @Basile, `ps` in the first terminal lists `sleep`, so it’s not  a shell built-in...

Comment: On `sash`  it is one. I tend to believe that on `zsh`  also

Comment: @Basile not on my copy of `sash`, or `zsh`. Try running `sleep --help` in both... But in any case, the relevant shell is the OP’s, and the question makes it clear it’s not a built-in there.

Comment: There’s even a list of `sash` built-ins in the Wikipedia article you linked to.